# Google Spreadsheets API with PHP – Fatal error: Uncaught exception

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-api, google-apps

I'm trying to get started with the google SpreadSheet API. I know there are a bunch of other languages but PHP is the only one I'm vaguely competent in. I keep falling at the first hurdle and getting:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google\Spreadsheet\Exception' in 
/Users/djave/Google Drive/Sites/practise/gdata/lib/Google/Spreadsheet/ServiceRequestFactory.php:48 

Stack trace: #0 /Users/djave/Google Drive/Sites/practise/gdata/lib/Google/Spreadsheet/SpreadsheetService.php(37): 
Google\Spreadsheet\ServiceRequestFactory::getInstance() 
  #1 /Users/djave/Google Drive/Sites/practise/gdata/index.php(32): Google\Spreadsheet\SpreadsheetService->getSpreadsheets() 
  #2 {main} thrown in /Users/djave/Google Drive/Sites/practise/gdata/lib/Google/Spreadsheet/ServiceRequestFactory.php on line 48
```

How this happens:

### Step 1 Download and add the folder [google-api-php-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)

Next, fiddle with the code until it works

```
set_include_path('lib/');

require_once 'lib/Google/Client.php';
require_once 'lib/Google/Service/Books.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
$client->setDeveloperKey("-------------------------------------");
$service = new Google_Service_Books($client);
$optParams = array('filter' => 'free-ebooks');
$results = $service->volumes->listVolumes('Henry David Thoreau', $optParams);

foreach ($results as $item) {
    echo $item['volumeInfo']['title'], "<br /> \n";
}
```

Result: prints out a list of books

### Step 2 Download and install [php-google-spreadsheet-client](https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client)

First off I copy the example exactly below what I have, then include all the right files until it can find everything:

```
set_include_path('lib/');

require_once 'lib/Google/Client.php';
require_once 'lib/Google/Service/Books.php';
require_once 'lib/Google/Spreadsheet/SpreadsheetService.php';
require_once 'lib/Google/Spreadsheet/ServiceRequestFactory.php';
require_once 'lib/Google/Spreadsheet/Exception.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
$client->setDeveloperKey("-------------------------------------");
$service = new Google_Service_Books($client);
$optParams = array('filter' => 'free-ebooks');
$results = $service->volumes->listVolumes('Henry David Thoreau', $optParams);

foreach ($results as $item) {
    echo $item['volumeInfo']['title'], "<br /> \n";
}

        $spreadsheetService = new Google\Spreadsheet\SpreadsheetService();
        $spreadsheetFeed = $spreadsheetService->getSpreadsheets();
        $spreadsheet = $spreadsheetFeed->getByTitle('MySpreadsheet');
        $worksheetFeed = $spreadsheet->getWorksheets();
```

But I just get

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google\Spreadsheet\Exception' in /Users/djave/Google Drive/Sites/practise/gdata/lib/Google/Spreadsheet/ServiceRequestFactory.php:48 Stack trace: #0 /Users/djave/Google Drive/Sites/practise/gdata/lib/Google/Spreadsheet/SpreadsheetService.php(37): Google\Spreadsheet\ServiceRequestFactory::getInstance() #1 /Users/djave/Google Drive/Sites/practise/gdata/index.php(23): Google\Spreadsheet\SpreadsheetService->getSpreadsheets() #2 {main} thrown in /Users/djave/Google Drive/Sites/practise/gdata/lib/Google/Spreadsheet/ServiceRequestFactory.php on line 48
```

I'm doing something really stupid, right? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you've forgotten to bootstrap the lib first: https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client#bootstrapping

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Spreadsheet\DefaultServiceRequest;
use Google\Spreadsheet\ServiceRequestFactory;

$serviceRequest = new DefaultServiceRequest($accessToken);
ServiceRequestFactory::setInstance($serviceRequest);
```

Answer (score 1):

Give edit permission to "client_email" field value in client_secret.json file by opening the actual spreadsheet, refer image.[image]